# My job search status is being displayed as interested when I'm not

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, jobs

So I have an account and *was* searching for a job but was hired back in January. When hired, I made sure to at least update my job search status to not looking.

Well I just received a message from an employer about an opportunity but well, you know, I'm not looking so I had to decline.

I made sure to double check my status and update my profile to include my new job.  It turns out that my status *is* currently set to not looking but I now changed it to block all.  Hitting save, it is still being shown as interested.

[image: currently selected]

[image: still interested...]

Is this just a cosmetic problem and I am actually set as blocking?  Or am I still being listed as interested and looking?

On the right, it *does* say that the `employer view` is `blocked` but shouldn't it say that on the main part of the page too?

I'm liking my job so far and have no intention of looking for another one so soon.

Comment: There's more than one way to explain that bug.  I don't get the problem, why don't you just remove your ad?

Comment: @UphillLuge Like, delete his account? That's like deleting your resume when you get hired and writing a new one from scratch the next time you want a job

Comment: Wow, I see why you were able to get that new programming job. You have impeccable handwriting with a mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Correction**: This only shows up on the employer view of your profile, which only appears to employers you have given access to (if they contacted you) and in search results (which you are blocking).  So basically, nobody will see this.

If you click over to the public view of your profile, this line does not ever appear.

<s>This is a cosmetic problem and you are set as blocked.  You do not show up in employer searches.  You can untick the full time checkbox and it will be removed from your profile (until we get a better fix in).</s>

Comment: Ok thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @Jeff This was not actually being shown to anyone -- see my correction to the answer above